# Combining multiple rows into single one using CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a trouble with saving multiple rows of a query into single one using CLOB.

I've tried this method suggested at ASK TOM https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537158500346658848
but i think i'm lacking some knowledge to properly bind variables of my query.

Could you please help me? or maybe there is another option for this query to be compressed into single row using a CLOB

Here is the query in question

```
Select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'||chr(10)||
'<OtherServices ServiceMonth="'|| to_char(framework.dim_calendar_pkg.get_startdate(FRAMEWORK.CTL_Session_Parameters_PKG.Get_BillingPeriod()),'YYYYMM')||'" Source ="CLIENT" UniqueFileID ="ID0000036">' as XML
from dual 
union all 
select CAST(XML as varchar2(2000)) as XML from (
with CTE as 
(SELECT   R.BS_TEXT          AS BillingDriver
           , F.CI_NAME          AS Signum
           , 1                  AS Quantity   -- not F.Quantity, as even non-billable should have quantity 1
           , CASE WHEN F.QUANTITY=0
                 THEN 'No'
                 ELSE 'Yes'
            END                 AS Billable            
    FROM CLIENT.FACTS F
    JOIN CLIENT.DIM_RESOURCEUNITS_VW R ON F.RU_ID = R.RU_ID
                  WHERE F.BILLINGPERIOD = FRAMEWORK.CTL_Session_Parameters_PKG.Get_BillingPeriod()
                    AND F.BILLINGPERIOD = F.SERVICEPERIOD
                    AND F.INPUT_SOURCE  IN ('CLIENT_CVS_NONPDV','CLIENT_CVS_PDV','CLIENT_CVS_PV')

)
SELECT
    XMLSERIALIZE(document
       XMLElement("Service", 
            XMLForest (C.BillingDriver AS "BillingDriver", 
                      C.Signum   AS "Signum", 
                      C.Quantity  AS "Quantity",
                      C.Billable  AS "Billable")
      )
      indent size=2) XML
      FROM CTE C)
UNION ALL
Select '</OtherServices>' AS XML from dual;



 SELECT   '201904'          AS ServiceMonth
         , 'CLIENT'        AS Source
         , 'ID0000038'      AS UniqueFileID
         , 'ViCS_MWPII_user' AS BillingDriver
          , VM.SIGNUM         AS "Signum-ID"
            , 1                 AS Quantity
            , 'Yes'             AS Billable
     FROM CLIENT.REF_CVS_VICS_MATRIX_VW VM
    WHERE  VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_BASE = 1 
      AND (VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_EMEA = 1  OR VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_AMCS = 1 OR VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_APAC = 1)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 from CLIENT.FACTS F
                  WHERE F.BILLINGPERIOD = FRAMEWORK.CTL_Session_Parameters_PKG.Get_BillingPeriod()
                    AND F.BILLINGPERIOD = F.SERVICEPERIOD
                    AND F.INPUT_SOURCE  IN ('CLIENT_MWP2_OPER','CLIENT_MWP2_COMP')
                    AND UPPER(F.CURRENT_USER) = UPPER(VM.SIGNUM))

    UNION ALL
    -- Signums with VICS_BASE and one of regional VICS_DESKTOPS, but without user in MWPII
    SELECT  '201904'          AS ServiceMonth
         , 'CLIENT'        AS Source
         , 'ID0000038'      AS UniqueFileID  
         , 'ViCS_PV'         AS BillingDriver
          , VM.SIGNUM        AS "Signum-ID"
            , 1                AS Quantity
            , 'Yes'            AS Billable
     FROM CLIENT.REF_CVS_VICS_MATRIX_VW  VM
     WHERE  VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_BASE = 1 
       AND (VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_EMEA = 1  OR VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_AMCS = 1 OR VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_APAC = 1)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from CLIENT.FACTS F
                  WHERE F.BILLINGPERIOD = FRAMEWORK.CTL_Session_Parameters_PKG.Get_BillingPeriod()
                    AND F.BILLINGPERIOD = F.SERVICEPERIOD   
                    AND F.INPUT_SOURCE  IN ('CLIENT_MWP2_OPER','CLIENT_MWP2_COMP')
                    AND UPPER(F.CURRENT_USER) = UPPER(VM.SIGNUM)) 
    UNION ALL
    -- Other signums with VICS_Base =1, but without regional VICS_Desktop
    SELECT   '201904'          AS ServiceMonth
         , 'CLIENT'        AS Source
         , 'ID0000038'      AS UniqueFileID
         , 'ViCS_Apps'       AS BillingDriver
          , VM.SIGNUM        AS "Signum-ID"
            , 1                AS Quantity
            , 'Yes'            AS Billable
     FROM CLIENT.REF_CVS_VICS_MATRIX_VW  VM
     WHERE      VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_BASE = 1 
       AND (VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_EMEA IS NULL OR VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_EMEA != 1)
       AND (VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_AMCS IS NULL OR VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_AMCS != 1)
       AND (VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_APAC IS NULL OR VM.ACCESS_TO_VICS_DESTKOP_APAC != 1)
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there an error that you face when you run this query? If so please share that. What is the expected output of your query? Can you create a masked mockup data which can help us understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Right now the query that i presented to You produces many rows (usually more than 5000) in a single column, i would need that to be in a single row, because later i'll have it being downloaded using APEX application in an XML format.

To be honest i have no clue how to even begin with creating a procedure to save an output of this query in a single row

Comment: If your question is about converting multiple rows of data into single row of multiple values (concatenated may be with a delimiter), I suggest checking Oracle's LISTAGG function.

Comment: I've tried, however i'll receive ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long as this produces a lot of data, this is why i'm trying to squeeze that into the CLOB but i don't know how to get it done.

Comment: Did you try looping through the records and appending it to a CLOB variable? - "https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_lob2.htm#1009290"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to convert multiple rows of data into a single CLOB value delimited by newline. In the cursor part you may want to replace with your query.

```
create table test(c clob);

declare
  lv_clob CLOB;

  cursor c
  is select rpad('*',level*2,' *')||chr(10) rec from dual connect by level <= 15;

  c_rec varchar2(100);--Holds each record from above cursor in each iteration

begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(lv_clob, TRUE);

  open c;
  loop
    fetch c into c_rec;
    exit when c%notfound;

    dbms_lob.append(lv_clob, c_rec);
  end loop;

  insert into test values(lv_clob);
  commit;

  dbms_lob.freetemporary(lv_clob);

end;

select * from test;
```

Output:

```
C
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```